# Binary crossentropy loss

Tags: neural-network, loss-function, optimization

When we have a binary classification problem, we use a sigmoid activation function in the output layer+ a binary crossentropy loss. We also need to one hot encode the target variable.This s a binary classification problem meaning that we can have some samples with `y_pred=0`. As we know the binary crossentropy loss has the quantity `log(y_pred)`, this means that we can have `log(0)` for samples that belong to class 0. However, `log(0)` is undefined ! So how the binary crossentropy is still computable ??? The same can be asked for softmax+ categorical crossentropy for multiclassification problems.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a value equal to the [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) will give you an offset in `log` that is large enough to not change your result but will give you an expression that you can evaluate:

```py
import numpy as np
print(0*np.log(0))
print(0*np.log(0+np.finfo(float).eps))
nan
-0.0
```

Comment: Careful doing this math. It is popular and easy but not always the best way to proceed. It can bias the results. Here is 1 conversation and 1 paper but there are many more. https://www.researchgate.net/post/Log_transformation_of_values_that_include_0_zero_for_statistical_analyses2 and https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3444996